# Changing a variable while debugging leads to NullPointerException

Tags: debugging, android-studio

It seems like I encountered a bug in Android Studio. When I change a variable during debugging and later call a method on that variable (it's a `String`, I try to call `contains`), I get a `NullPointerException`.

See this screenshot:

[image]

When I push <kbd>F8</kbd> on this point, I get a `NullPointerException`:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Is this a bug, or am I missing something here?